# Getting black screen when app returning from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm dealing with a tricky bug on my app. I have a chat view controller where I deal with keyboard showing and hiding. But the weird part is when putting the app on background.

This is the view controller before going to background (tapping the home button)

[image]

And this is the app when returning from background

[image]

If I put the app on background using the home button, the black screen only appears for a second, but if I block the phone and then unlock, the black screen keeps there.

This is how I deal with the keyboard

```
- (void)keyboardWillShowWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  //We adjust inverted insets because tableview will be inverted
  CGFloat displacementDistance = rect.size.height - self.composeBarView.bounds.size.height;
  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.composeBarView.bounds.size.height, 0, displacementDistance, 0);
  [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y - displacementDistance, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}

- (void)keyboardWillDismissWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  //We adjust inverted insets because tableview will be inverted
  CGFloat displacementDistance = rect.size.height - self.composeBarView.bounds.size.height;
  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.composeBarView.bounds.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
  [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + displacementDistance, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

The tableView used to display the messages is inverted in order to display the first message at the bottom. Here's how I do it:

```
- (void)setupTableView
{
  self.tableView.delegate = self;
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;
  //We adjust inverted insets because tableview will be inverted
  self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.composeBarView.bounds.size.height, 0, 0, 0);
  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500.0;
  self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 30.0;
  self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
  [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MessagesDateHeader" bundle:nil] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"MessagesDateHeader"];
  
  // Table View is inverted so we display last messages at the bottom instead of top
  self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnTableView)];
  tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Also, I have `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` set on `viewDidLoad`

Anyone can give me a hint of what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Try Xcode's View Debugging feature.  It should show you what views it thinks are being displayed and their relationships.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI)`? This rotates the view, but doesn't change the order of the messages

Comment: Befor app in background. Check your keyword is present or not on the screen.  For keyword dismiss method or view down  You can use  [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: @lufritz No, it doesn't change the order. What I do whit that is flipping the tableview upside down to mimic and inverted tableview. Is not on the question but I also apply that transformation again to my cells and section headers to avoid to see the content upside down.

Comment: Maybe it is the reason of the black screen. Why don't you just iterate reversed through the data array? The transformation is more heavy on the cpu and it's not necessary.

Comment: @lufritz Because I want to display the first cell at the bottom of the tableview.

Comment: It seems the problem is due because the frame change on the table view. If I remove the setFrame lines on the handling of the keyboard, the black screen doesn't appears, but I need the tableview to scroll up along with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a similar problem. Issue was the resizing of the tableView when keyboard appears/disappears based on its frame.
What I did was set a constraint between the bottom of the tableView and the superView and then change its constant with the appearance/disappearance of the keyboard.

Instead of relying on `keyboardWillShowWithRect:` and `keyboardWillDismissWithRect:` you can use listen to `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` and handle it like follows

```
- (void) keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardFrameEnd = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrameEnd = [self.view convertRect:keyboardFrameEnd toView:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]
                          delay:0.f
                        options:[userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue] << 16
                     animations:^{
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - keyboardFrameEnd.origin.y;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                   } completion:nil];
}
```

`[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` is used so that view shows the whole animation